# C# WCF Client <--> Service Behavior switching

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, protocol-buffers

lets say I want to have a Service that uses 2 different forms of serialization
and i have a client that has 2 buttons, 1 for the first behavior (XML) and the second one for lets say (Protobuf)

Is there something I need to do in order to let the client choose which serilization should be used?

I got 2 endpointBehaviors in my app.config for the service.
XML and Protobuf.

Am I missing something?
My Interface got only the Protocontract attribute
And my DataContract got all of the protoMember attributes.

Anyone knows what I want to do and can help me out?
Sorry for no code, its theorem at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide you code please.

I think you miss the second interface.
You need an Interface for each form of serialization.

Something like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFirstService
{
    //Methods
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ISecondService
{
    //Methods
}

[ServiceBehavior]
public class YourClass: IFirstService, ISecondService
{
    //Methods
}
```

Comment: IFirstService is for XML implementation. ISecondService is for Protobuf

Comment: oh my god, i love you so much. I cant belive i overlooked that. It works like a charm now! I cant be more thankfull. But what about just one interface, to maintain two is harder than one. Any idea? But thank you, that solves my problem for now ^^

Comment: I don't think you can do it with one interface. So you need to maintain them both.